# Why DON'T we use the property in initializer methods? Use the instance variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why DON'T we use the property in initializer methods and to Use the instance variable?

```
init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.someString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@”Mike”, @”Jones”] autorelease];
    }
    return self;
}
```

vs:

```
init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _someString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@”Mike”, @”Jones”] autorelease];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Perharps line  _someString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@”Mike”, @”Jones”] autorelease]; is not correct. There is no need to use autorelease because your class should keep the reference to that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to do

```
_someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@”Mike”, @”Jones”];
```

without the `autorelease`. I assume your property to be `retain` or (better) `copy`.

You don't want to call methods in init and dealloc, as they can easily have side effects, either here (now or later) or in a subclass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please be more specific on side effects?

Comment: That's the problem - you just don't know what the method you call will exactly do. It may rely on a fully initialized object, but at this point the object is still in construction. For example, you might later change the setter method to do some other stuff or bookkeeping, and this relies on initialization code that is called later. It must not be code in this class that gives problems, it can easily happen when subclassing, too, when this method gets overridden.